# What is the most efficient way of storing and generating a hierarchy of categories?

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, categories

I'm creating a basic shopping cart in PHP and was wondering, what is the best way of storing and generating a list of categories in a hierarchy format with unlimited subcategories?

Currently I load the main categories and then `foreach` I get the subcategories from the database and so on, which on a large site would create over 100 queries.

So whats a better way of doing things?

Heres my current MySQL table structure:

```
cat_id  
cat_name
cat_desc
cat_parent_id
status
priority
```

I'm aiming for **1** query.

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11497724/1446794) to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11497202/1446794) for some recursive functions you could use that will eliminate the need to call your database for each category in a loop.

Comment: How many sub category levels does your code support? Unlimited?

Comment: Yes, there is no "max-depth", and it will recurse as deep as the deepest nested category in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does this pretty well:

see: http://codex.wordpress.org/File:WP3.0-ERD.png and http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Taxonomy

If you go this route
This [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query) has some question query logic for grabbing categories that you might find useful ([related stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155565/query-multiple-custom-taxonomy-terms-in-wordpress-2-8))

The key point is that the table with categories has an entry so you can let it know if the category has a parent category (Allowing you to join the table to itself).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: [Category Hierarchy (PHP/MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452472/category-hierarchy-php-mysql)

It uses one query to get all your categories from the database then manipulates the array to create child categories. I modified the answer to use in Codeigniter and it works great. Can post the modified code here if you're wanting to use Codeigniter.