# Wordpress Query Posts Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I currently have a checkbox based search and filter on my wordpress site.

Basically it works using this wp_query

```
$queryObject = new WP_Query(array("post_type"=>'toy','posts_per_page'=>999999, 
    'category__and' => $_POST['myListOfCategories']));
```

I want to move away from using categories (as it's making using the blog a pain)

So I've set everything up using custom taxonomies now and notice there is no "taxonomy__and".

Does anyone know of a way to use WP_Query to search for posts using taxonomies in the same way category__and and works?

e.g. I pass multiple taxonomy id's and it only returns posts which have all of them linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the other posters here is the final answer to my question:

```
$queryObject = new WP_Query(array("post_type"=>'toy','posts_per_page'=>10,'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'toy_cats',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' =>  array(14,20,39,42),
            'operator' => 'AND' )
    )));
```

The above code will only show posts that have the "toy" post type, is in the taxonomy "toy_cats" and is is assigned to ALL the following term id's 14 AND 20 AND 39 AND 42

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

You should be able to use something like this;

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'action', 'comedy' )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'actor',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have pass multiple taxonomy in Query_posts in Wordpress

See below URL It is very help full to you:-

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25999/how-to-pass-url-parameters-for-advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-multiple-terms-for

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10713/wp-3-1-getting-tax-query-to-work-in-query-posts

[Query multiple custom taxonomy terms in Wordpress 2.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155565/query-multiple-custom-taxonomy-terms-in-wordpress-2-8)

or try it

```
query_posts( array(
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'tax1',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array('term1', 'term2'),
      'operator' => 'OR'
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'tax2',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array('term3', 'term4'),
      'operator' => 'AND'
    ),
) );
```