# WP Query Post Count is always 0

Tags: wordpress, api

I have a lot of scheduled posts (location) in my db, and i want to show only the taxonomies (locationtype), which have published posts.

therefore i created a check_term_posts($term_id) function

but it always returns 0.

WP Query seems to be the only way to accomplish that, as $term->count seems to deliver everything.

```
    protected function check_term_posts($term_id) {
            $args = [
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'location',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'tax_query' => [[
                    'taxonomy' => 'locationtype',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $term_id
                ]]
            ];

            $q = new \WP_Query($args);
            return $q->post_count;
    }
```

$q->post_count is always zero

Comment: See this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250957/wordpress-query-posts-taxonomy?rq=1 .  It is using 'id' field instead of 'term_id' for taxonomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to replace

```
'field' => 'term_id', to 'field' => 'id',
```

your code become like this

```
$args = [
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'location',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'tax_query' => [[
                    'taxonomy' => 'locationtype',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $term_id
                ]]
            ];
```